How to update file changes in lowerdir to mergedir in overlayfs?
I create a overlayfs by this:
sudo mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=lower1:lower2,upperdir=upper,workdir=worker merge


Can I just copy the files to the upper directory or delete the files in it?
When I copy a new file (same name in lower2) to lower1, how can I update it in merge?

Now, I update it by following steps, is this legal?

xx file in lower2/dir/xx
cp xx (new file) to lower1/dir/xx
rm merge/dir/xx
rm upper/dir/xx
merge/dir/xx file is same with lower1/dir/xx

